# The modulus result is always wrong

Tags: java

I want to create a simple calculator.E.g. $21.37 can be changed to 21 1-dollar coin, 0 50-cent coin, 1 20-cent coin.However, my remainder result is always wrong and I cannot understand why. The following is my code,please help,many thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Question extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JLabel amt,dollar,fifty,title,result,error,creator;
    private TextField tb1,tb2,tb3;
    private JButton count;
    public Question()
    {
        setSize(400,300);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(null);
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        count = new JButton("=");
        title = new JLabel("Calculate Change");
        amt = new JLabel("Enter the amount:");
        dollar = new JLabel("1 Dollar Coin:");
        fifty = new JLabel("50 Cent Coin:");
        error = new JLabel("wrong information.");
        creator = new JLabel("Created by ?????");
        Font bold = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,15);
        Font wrong = new Font("Arial",Font.ITALIC,12);
        Font smaller = new Font("Arial",Font.ITALIC,10);
        error.setForeground(Color.red);
        tb1 = new TextField(13);
        tb2=new TextField(12);
        tb3= new TextField(12);
        tb2.setEnabled(false);
        tb3.setEnabled(false);
        creator.setFont(smaller);
        error.setFont(wrong);
        title.setFont(bold);
        title.setBounds(130,-14,150,40);
        amt.setBounds(20, 20, 120, 20);
        dollar.setBounds(40, 45, 120, 20);
        fifty.setBounds(40, 70, 120, 20);
        tb1.setBounds(160, 21, 90, 24);
        tb2.setBounds(160, 45, 90, 20);
        tb3.setBounds(160, 70, 90, 20);
        error.setBounds(260,170,150,20);
        count.setBounds(100,200,90,20);
        creator.setBounds(240,220,180,20);
        contentPane.add(title);
        contentPane.add(amt);
        contentPane.add(dollar);
        contentPane.add(fifty);
        contentPane.add(tb1);
        contentPane.add(tb2);
        contentPane.add(tb3);
        contentPane.add(error);
        contentPane.add(creator);
        contentPane.add(count);
        count.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        try
        {
            //String input = tb1.getText();
            double convert = Double.parseDouble(tb1.getText());
            if((e.getSource() == count) && (convert >=1)) 
            {
                double result;
                result = convert /1;
                convert = convert % 1;
               int result2 = (int)result;
                String result3 = String.valueOf(result2);
                tb2.setText(result3);

            }
            if((convert >= 0.5) && (convert < 0.99))
            {
                tb3.setText("1");
                convert = convert % 0.5;
                  String result4 = String.valueOf(convert);
                error.setText(result4);
            }
           }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            error.setText("Invalid input.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Question frame = new Question();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, what is the expected output and please refer to the line which is of interest.

Comment: The code is full of useless things, post only the relevant code (actionPerformed) and post an example of input/output.

Comment: You shouldn't use `double`s or `float`s when you need exact precision. A decimal number like `21.37` can't be stored in a floating-point variable exactly. See also [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) and use integer arithmetic (in cents) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You should format your results. So instead of:

```
String result3 = String.valueOf(result2);
```

Consider doing:

```
String result3 = String.format("%.2f", result2);
```

This will trim off the trailing numbers and round your number for display.

For more details on how to use `String.format(...)` please check out the [java.util.Formatter API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: Hehe I was just typing it. Btw. it should be result4 I think ;)

Comment: @enterbios: it's for both result3 *and* result4, I think. ;) But thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

You get the wrong results because you use `% 0.5`

```
double convert = Double.parseDouble("21.37");

int oneDollarCoins = (int) convert; // throws away the fractions
System.out.println(oneDollarCoins); // prints 21
convert -= oneDollarCoins;
int cents = (int) (convert * 100);
System.out.println(cents); // prints 37
// modulo the cents % 50, 20, ...
// don't use % 0.5
```

For small numbers `double` should be fine, but for bigger numbers you can get wrong results as mentioned by the others.